# My lambda function returns True regardless, i am trying to create a new column in the data frame that checks for null values. What went wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import codecademylib
import pandas as pd

ad_clicks = pd.read_csv('ad_clicks.csv')

print(ad_clicks.head(10))


ad_clicks.groupby('utm_source').user_id.count().reset_index()

ad_clicks['is_click'] = ad_clicks.ad_click_timestamp.apply(lambda x : False if x is None else True)
print(ad_clicks.head(10))
```

Comment: Print out `ad_clicks.ad_click_timestamp` - it could be something like `NaN` which is a numpy/pandas object, not None.

Comment: What is `ad_clicks.ad_click_timestamp.dtype` ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `.notna()`;

```
ad_clicks['is_click'] = ad_clicks['ad_click_timestamp'].notna()
```

Comment: Great answer and speedier than `apply` but may not work depending on the column's dtype. If its a string dtype, empty strings aren't False.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, but notna() threw an error 'object has no attribute'.  However i got the code right : ad_clicks['is_click'] = ~ad_clicks['ad_click_timestamp'].isnull()

Comment: @JasonDias Weird, the documentation explicitly says that ```notna()```/```isna()``` is the same as ```notnull()```/```isnull()```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the axis as in the documentation for rows :-
[Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#:~:text=Apply%20a%20function%20along%20an,columns%20(%20axis%3D1%20).)

Try this :-

```
ad_clicks['is_click'] = ad_clicks.ad_click_timestamp.apply(lambda x : False if x is None else True, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, but it threw an error 'unexpected keyword argument'. However i figured the code out  ad_clicks['is_click'] = ~ad_clicks['ad_click_timestamp'].isnull()